# How to display only a process and its descendant processes on htop?

Tags: htop

I want to monitor only a process and its children processes on `htop`. Filtering on the name of the parent process lists only the parent process, not its children. How do I show the children processes too?

Comment: There is an issue [76 in the new htop repo](https://github.com/htop-dev/htop/issues/76). Vote for it!

Comment: Related: https://github.com/ClementTsang/bottom/issues/734

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Under Linux, you can do:

```
htop -p `pstree -p $PID | perl -ne 'push @t, /\((\d+)\)/g; END { print join ",", @t }'`
```

where `$PID` is the root process. This works as follows:

1. The list of the wanted processes are obtained with `pstree`, using the `-p` option to list them with their PID.
2. The output is piped to a Perl script that retrieves the PID's, using a regular expression (here, `\((\d+)\)`), and outputs them separated with commas.
3. This list is provided as an argument of `htop -p`.

For other OS like Mac OS, you may need to adapt the regular expression that retrieves the PIDs.

Note: It is unfortunately not possible to update the list with new children that are spawn later, because once `htop` has been executed, one cannot do anything else. This is a limitation of `htop` (current version: 2.0.2).

Comment: `$PID` can be the name of the process, or it has to be the id?

Comment: @becko `$PID` has to be the pid, but you can get the id from the name of the process with `pgrep`.

Comment: this will not update when new children are spawned though... would love to use sth like it for monitoring only stuff in my tmux session

Comment: @black_puppydog me too!

Comment: On macOS with `pstree` from homebrew: `htop -p \`pstree -p $PID | perl -ne 'push @t, /--- (\d+) /g; END { print join ",", @t }'\``

Comment: @black_puppydog In addition to explanations, I've added a note saying that it is not possible to update the list with new children. This is a limitation of `htop`.

Comment: @jpsim Thanks for the information. After some search, it does not seem to be the only format under Mac OS. Each user should check the `pstree -p` output format and adapt the regular expression. I've expanded my answer to give explanations and suggest to adapt the regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

```
htop -p $(ps -ef | awk -v proc=$PID 'BEGIN{pids[proc]=1;printf "%s",proc} {if(pids[$3]==1){printf ",%s",$2; pids[$2]=1}}')
```

Where `$PID` is the root process id.

Use awk to create a comma separated list of the specified process and its descendant processes and pass the output to `htop -p`.

Answer (score 0):

```
htop -p $(ps -ef | awk -v proc=15305 '$3 == proc { cnt++;if (cnt == 1) { printf "%s",$2 } else { printf ",%s",$2 } }')
```

Use awk to create a comma separated list of process id's from the output of ps -ef passing the parent process id as proc and then passing this out to htop -p.

Answer (score 0):

on macOS (prolly works on linux too), a potential workaround that works for me is to identify a search phrase for each process in the hierarchy and use `htop`s `FILTER` pattern to search for each term separated by a `|`. this allows a live monitor that captures child processes too as long as part of your search pattern captures the child process.

so if you have the following process hierarchy you want to monitor:

```
top-process-A
\__ subprocess-B
    \__ subsubprocess-C
        \__ subsubsubprocess-D
```

use the `FILTER` pattern `A|B|C|D`.

If the patterns are less specific, this might capture some other processes you dont care about, but it will drastically reduce the number of visible processes in the current viewport.
this might be untenable though the more processes you are trying to monitor, especially if they all have different names.

Comment: Welcome & thanks for contributing. I am anyhow afraid that this answer would produce suboptimal results compared with the 3 existing ones.